# IONIC4 : how to use cssClass for Loading , it is doesn't work

Tags: css, ionic4

I want to change ion-loading style using cssClass ,my code as follow:

loading.page.ts :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-loading',
    templateUrl: './loading.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./loading.page.scss'],
})
export class LoadingPage {

constructor(public lLoadingController: LoadingController) { }

async  presentCunstomLoading() {
    const loading = await this.lLoadingController.create({
        spinner: 'hide',
        duration: 500000,
        content: 'Please wait...',
        translucent: true,
        cssClass: 'custom-class'
    });
    return await loading.present();
}
}
```

loading.page.scss ::

`

```
app-loading {
  .custom-class {
    background: #e0b500;
  }
```

}`

loading.page.html :

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-button (click)="presentModal()">open modal</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

What's problem with this? Anyone can help me . I am confused. Thanks advance.

Comment: Try `ion-loading.custom-class {.loading-wrapper {/*Background Styles*/}ion-spinner {/*Spinner styles*/}}` This works for my in Ionic 3.

Comment: @Nacorga hi, I have a little confused "ion-loading" . This is my component name or refer annother ...?

Comment: Hi @Stellina! `ion-loading` is the name of the html element that contains the loading and appears when your app starts loading

Comment: Hi @Nacorga , I edited my question add the template . Therefore in my case the ‘ion-loading’ is refer 'ion-button' . Maybe I make mistake ... I not see ion-loading in IONIC4 . Loading is created by LoadingControll .

Answer (score 3):

theme/variables.scss

```
ion-loading.custom-loading {
  .loading-wrapper {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
}
```

I don't know why, but it works in Ionic4.

If you write in loading.page.scss, it doesn't work.

Comment: It is incredible the nonsense we have to go through to achieve basic things like a transparent background for a loading controller in ionic... thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm Using IONIC 4.**

```
this.myLoading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({ 
  spinner: null,
  message: '<ion-img src="assets/gif/loading.gif"></ion-img>',
  cssClass: 'custom-loading'
});
await this.myLoading.present();
```

**at theme/variables.scss**

```
ion-loading.custom-loading {
  .loading-wrapper {
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

There you go. Now you have a custom loading with transparent background.

Comment: It is incredible the nonsense we have to go through to achieve basic things like a transparent background for a loading controller in ionic... thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Rano Paimin, your solution doesn't work, so I'll improve your answer:

**I'm Using IONIC 4**

```
this.myLoading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({ 
  spinner: null, -> here you can add others spinners ou set null 
  remove this attribute -> message: '<ion-img src="assets/gif/loading.gif"></ion-img>', 
  cssClass: 'custom-loading'
});
await this.myLoading.present();
```

**at theme/variables.scss**

```
ion-loading.custom-loading {
  .loading-wrapper {
    background: #ffffff url("assets/gif/loading.gif") no-repeat center;
  }
}
```

If you want change dimensions you can change these properties:

```
  background-size: 100px 100px; /* to change dimension of background */
  padding-top: 36px; /* padding top of white square */
  padding-bottom: 36px; /* padding bottom of white square */
  border-radius: 0.8rem; /* border-radius white square */
```

I hope that helps you.